# How to check fo duplicities using Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following simple kind of XML, where @id is string:

```
<root>
    <item id="a1"/>
    <item id="a2"/>
    <item id="b2"/>
    <item id="a3"/>
</root>
```

I can have a lot of item nodes in XML (> 30000). What I want to check is, that @id is unique across all elements. Is it possible to make this check via XPath (returning true/false) ? If so, can somebody post how - ideally the most effective solution ? Is there some operator which returns only unique items from sequence ?

EDIT:
Found myself the solution myself:

```
count(distinct-values(//item/@id)) = count(//item/@id)
```

Not sure if it is the most effective one.

Comment: To one who downwoted this question - why you ahve done this ? It is relevant question.

Comment: I have found after 2 hours digging into the problem the following solution myself count(distinct-values(//item/@id)) = count(//item/@id), not sure if it is the most effective.

Comment: I would suggest you post the solution as an answer and validate it so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found myself the solution myself:

count(distinct-values(//item/@id)) = count(//item/@id)

Not sure if it is the most effective one.